# Rails select from multiple tables to create collection for select field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

I'm trying to dynamically build a collection where each array contains a value from two separate tables.

The Models:

```
#/models/user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :user_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me,
  :first_name, :last_name, :permanent_address, :permanent_city,
  :permanent_state, :permanent_zip, :home_phone, :mobile_phone, :role,
  :tenant_attributes, :rents_attributes

  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :last_name, :presence => true
  validates :permanent_address, :presence => true
  validates :permanent_city, :presence => true
  validates :permanent_zip, :presence => true
  validates :first_name, :presence => true
  validates :home_phone, :presence => true

  has_one :app
  has_one :tenant, :foreign_key => :users_id
  has_many :rents
  has_many :maints

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tenant
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rents, allow_destroy: true

end

#/models/tenant.rb

class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :users
  belongs_to :units
  attr_accessible :lease_begin, :lease_end, :rent_share, :users_id, :units_id

  has_many :maints

end
```

The Helper Method (so far):

```
#/helpers/users_helper.rb

def tenants 

  tenants = Tenant.select([:id, ??? ])

  tenants.map {|u| [u.???, u.id]}

end
```

The form field:

```
<%= f.input :tenant_id, :collection => tenants %>
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is select the :id from the Tenants table and then the associated :first_name + :last_name (represented by "???" above) from the Users table to populate the collection arrays this would generate.

What's the best approach here?

Answer (score 2):

If your helper is specifically used just for this `input` then I believe you have the correct thought on your query, in that you are concerned on retrieving just the required columns.

To retrieve `tenant`s including attributes from their `belongs_to :user` relation, your helper definition needs to be updated to:

```
# app/helpers/users_helper.rb
def tenants 
  tenants = Tenant.joins(:user).select('tenants.id as tenant_id, users.first_name, users.last_name')
  tenants.map { |u| [ [u.first_name, u.last_name].join(' '), u.tenant_id ]}
end
```

The `tenants` helper then returns a nested array of `first_name` and `last_name` joined with a space as one element and `tenant_id` as the second element array.

With the updated helper your view would be:

```
<%= f.select :tenant_id, :collection => tenants %>
```

Note the use of [`select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html) helper here which is more suitable for this case.